# Why TortoiseSvn breaks locks during an update?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Here in my company we still use the Lock-Modify-Unlock Model. Yes, I know....

I updated my tortoise and after this, everytime that I need to update my working copy it breaks the locks in the files that I´m working. 
Anybody knows why this happen? Can I change this behavior?
 I searched on Google but I couldn´t find an answer. 
My Tortoise version is TortoiseSVN 1.8.4, Build 24972 - 32 Bit.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/svn-1-8-causing-locks-to-be-broken-on-update-td183572i20.html

It´s a bug in Tortoise 1.8 and old servers. Before server 1.6.17